# 店舗マスタと会員マスタの緯度経度情報から、総当たりで距離を求める方法について

Tags: python

#### 追記

二重ループで距離を出すことはできましたが、これを配列に詰めていく方法がわかりません。理想は行＝会員番号、列＝店舗名のクロス集計表のような形式にしたいです。
また、会員数が約15万人程度いるためforループだと重く、他に何か良い方法があるようでしたら教えていただきたいです。

```
!pip install geopy
from geopy.distance import geodesic

customer_no1 = customer_master1.iloc[:,0] store_no = store_master.iloc[:,0] customer_list1 = customer_master1.iloc[:,3:] store_list = store_master.iloc[:,2:] 

for c in range(len(customer_list1)):
    for s in range(len(store_list)):
    dis = geodesic((customer_list1["Lat"].loc[c,],customer_list1["Lon"].loc[c,]), (store_list["緯度"].loc[s,],store_list["経度"].loc[s,])).km 
    print(customer_no1[c],",",store_no[s],",",f"{dis:.0f}")
```

#### 前提

会員マスタと店舗マスタの緯度・経度情報から、会員ごとに各店舗までの距離を求めたいと思っております。

会員マスタ、店舗マスタのデータの持ち方としては、それぞれ住所とそれに対応する緯度・経度が格納されているイメージです。（添付画像ご参照ください）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 質問本題

以下のように2地点間の緯度・経度から距離を求める関数を定義したのですが、この関数をもとにして行＝各会員、列＝各店舗として各セルに該当する距離が入るようなマスタを作成したいと思っております。

色々とやり方を考えてみたのですが、良いやり方が思いつかず、どのような方法でやれば良いのかコード付きで教えていただけますと幸いです。

```
##モジュールimport
from math import sin, cos, acos, radians

earth_rad = 6371

##関数定義
def latlng_to_xyz(lat, lng):
rlat, rlng = radians(lat), radians(lng)
coslat = cos(rlat)
return coslat*cos(rlng), coslat*sin(rlng), sin(rlat)

def dist_on_sphere(pos0, pos1, radius=earth_rad):
xyz0, xyz1 = latlng_to_xyz(*pos0), latlng_to_xyz(*pos1)
return acos(sum(x * y for x, y in zip(xyz0, xyz1)))*radius
```

#### アウトプットイメージ

```
店舗A 店舗B 店舗C 店舗D ・ ・ ・
会員A 距離 距離 距離 距離
会員B 距離 距離 距離 距離
・
・
・
・
```

Comment: 店舗と会員の経緯度をつかって計算

Comment: 会員方向と店舗方向の二重ループで、店舗と会員の経緯度を使って得られた距離を配列に詰めていけば良いだけなのでは？
とりえあず、現状のプログラムを質問に追加して、助言を得るのが良いと思います。
2地点間の緯度・経度から距離を求める関数は、distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)という感じで二組の経緯度を引数として、距離(キロメーター)を返せば良いのではないですか？「return coslatcos(rlng), coslatsin(rlng), sin(rlat)」というようにたくさんの値を返す必要はないように思います。

Comment: この記事が参考になるのでは？ [緯度経度から距離を算出するPythonのライブラリ ― GeoPy](https://h-memo.com/python-geopy-distance/)

Comment: この手のやりたい事を実現するには、「目の前の問題を単純化・一般化する」「細かい手順に分割して一つずつ解決」していくのが定石だと思います。 / 店舗や会員ではなく、単純に「2点間の距離を求める」方法を用意して、(既にコメントが付いてますが) ループを回して総当りする…といった方法が考えられます。 / 「いろいろ考えたけど良いやり方が思いつかず」も、結局何に困っているのかが曖昧でこのままだと回答が付きづらい印象です。

Comment: 色々な方法がありそうですが、切っ掛けの一つとしてこれらの記事が参考になりそうです。[Finding the distance between two lists of geographic coordinates](https://medium.com/@danalindquist/finding-the-distance-between-two-lists-of-geographic-coordinates-9ace7e43bb2f), [Calculating the Haversine Distance Between Two Geo-locations with Python](https://codeburst.io/calculate-haversine-distance-between-two-geo-locations-with-python-439186315f1b)